# vaildate multiple input text field with jquery

Tags: jquery, html

i have multiple set of input fields which contains for name and email. if user can add new set of input fields by clicking add new button. at the time of submitting form how to validate these newly added input fields? I heard this can be done by using `jquery.each`, but i don't know how to implement it.
Any help?

code here in below:

```
<div class="subsriber_list_view">
    <div class="sr">
Name:<input type="text" class="subsribe_name" autocomplete="off" name="name[]">
Email:<input type="text" class="subsribe_mail" autocomplete="off" name="email[]">
</div>      
<div class="subsriber_list_container" id="sr1">
    <div class="sr">
    Name:<input type="text" class="subsribe_name" autocomplete="off" name="name[]">
    Email:<input type="text" class="subsribe_mail" autocomplete="off" name="email[]">
    </div>
    <div class="s_remove">
     <a href="javascript:void(0)">Remove</a>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="subsriber_list_container" id="sr2">
       <div class="sr">
    Name:<input type="text" class="subsribe_name" autocomplete="off" name="name[]">
        Email:<input type="text" class="subsribe_mail" autocomplete="off" name="email[]">
       </div>
    <div class="s_remove">
            <a href="javascript:void(0)">Remove</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="subsriber_list_container" id="sr3">
            <div class="sr">
                Name:<input type="text" class="subsribe_name" autocomplete="off" name="name[]">
                Email:<input type="text" class="subsribe_mail" autocomplete="off" name="email[]">
            </div>
        <div class="s_remove">
            <a href="javascript:void(0)">Remove</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="subsriber_list_container" id="sr4">
            <div class="sr">
                Name:<input type="text" class="subsribe_name" autocomplete="off" name="name[]">
                Email:<input type="text" class="subsribe_mail" autocomplete="off" name="email[]">
            </div>
        <div class="s_remove">
            <a href="javascript:void(0)">Remove</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>  
<input type="hidden" name="referer_id" class="referer" value="1">
<input type="submit" name="subscriber_submit" class="subscriber" value="Subsribe to Join1000">
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js'></script>

<script type='text/javascript'>

    var me = jQuery || $.noConflict();
    me(document).ready(function() {
        me(".add_new").click(function() {
            me('span.err').remove(); // clear all existing error messages
            me('input.subsribe_name').each(function() {                 
                $subsribe_name = me(this).val();
                $subsribe_mail = me(this).val();
                if($subsribe_name == '') {
                    me('input.subsribe_name').after('<span class="err">Please Enter Referer name</span>').focus();
                    return false;
                }               

           var intId = me(".subsriber_list_view .subsriber_list_container").length + 1;
           var fieldWrapper = me("<div class=\"subsriber_list_container\"  id=\"sr" + intId + "\"/>");
           var fName = me("<div class='sr'>Name:<input type='text' class='subsribe_name' autocomplete='off'name='name[]' /> Email:<input type='text' class='subsribe_mail' autocomplete='off' name='email[]' />");
           var removeButton = me("<div class='s_remove'><a href='javascript:void(0)'>Remove</a></div></div></div>");
           fieldWrapper.append(fName);
           fieldWrapper.append(removeButton);      
           me(".subsriber_list_view").append(fieldWrapper);
           removeButton.click(function() {
               me(this).parent().remove();         
           });  
           });
        });     
        me('#sr .subscriber').click(function() {
            me('span.err').remove(); // clear all existing error messages
            $subsribe_name = me('.subsribe_name').val();
            $subsribe_mail = me('.subsribe_mail').val();
            if($subsribe_name == '') {
                me('input.subsribe_name').after('<span class="err">Please Enter Referer name</span>').focus();  return false;
            }
            if($subsribe_mail == '') {
                me('input.subsribe_mail').after('<span class="err">Please Enter Referer mail ID</span>').focus();
                return false;
            }
            var filter=/^([\w-]+(?:\.[\w-]+)*)@((?:[\w-]+\.)*\w[\w-]{0,66})\.([a-z]{2,6}(?:\.[a-z]{2})?)$/i
            if (!filter.test($subsribe_mail)) {
                    me('input.subsribe_mail').after('<span class="err">Please input a valid email address!</span>').focus();
                    return false;               
            }           
        });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You may want like this.., [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Dwzc9/61/)

```
<form method="post" action="" id="userForm">
    <input type="text" name="name" />
    <input type="text" name="email" />
    <input type="text" name="name1" />
    <input type="text" name="email1" />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="submitBtn" />
</form>



$(function() {

 $("#submitBtn").click(function() {

 $("#userForm input[type=text]").each(function() {

        if(!$(this).val()) {
            alert("Please Fill All Fields");
            $(this).addClass('warn');
            $(this).focus();
            return false;
     }    
    });
    return false;
});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

plugins will make your like easier and managed, anyhow attach a click handler to form submit button

```
$("#form-submit-btn").on("click",function(e){
 e.preventDefault();//prevent default form submission

 //perform your validation login
 //if the form is valid
  //$(this).closest('form').submit();
 //else
  //show error messages

});
```